# Python - Fuzzy matching result in new column for category based on ratio over 80

Tags: python, fuzzy

I would like to scan a folder to pick up all the files end with '.txt' and then create a data frame by creating a new column for categorization with similar file names (partial score of ratio >=80)

```
import os
path = '../../../files'
text_files = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith('.txt')]
text_files 

from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process

s1 = "programmi.txt"
s2 = "programmi-2.txt"
fuzz.ratio(s1, s2)
```

The result I expect to see is like below:

[image]

Comment: How does the posted code relate to what you "expect to see"?

Comment: get the file name and use matching function, name with 80% match group them together

Comment: Hi, I am new to Python so want to learn how to make it work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution which uses two for loops to compare each text to all the others to obtain the fuzz ratio needed for the categorisations.

```
import pandas as pd
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process

txt_list = [
    "programmi.txt",
    "readl-001.txt",
    "dict_class124.txt",
    "readl-002.txt",
    "programmi-2.txt",
    "programmi-re.txt",
    "readl-003.txt",
    "dict_class125.txt",
    "dict_class1264.txt",
    "hello world"

]

list_categorised_texts = []
txt_category = []
category_index = 0
threshold = 80

# two for loops since we need to compare each text to all the others
for txt_1 in txt_list:

    if txt_1 not in list_categorised_texts:  # if the first text of the current pair is not yet categorised, add as new category
        category_index += 1
        list_categorised_texts.append(txt_1)
        txt_category.append(category_index)
        
    for txt_2 in txt_list:
        
        if txt_1 == txt_2:  # we don't want to compare the same texts
            continue
        
        elif txt_2 in list_categorised_texts:  # skip already classified texts
            continue

        else:  # if the txt_2 is similar, add to list of classified texts with corresponding category
            similarity = fuzz.ratio(txt_1, txt_2)
            if similarity >= threshold:
                list_categorised_texts.append(txt_2)
                txt_category.append(category_index)
        
            
data = {
    'texts': list_categorised_texts,
    'category': txt_category
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df.to_markdown())
```

Result:

```
|    | texts              |   category |
|---:|:-------------------|-----------:|
|  0 | programmi.txt      |          1 |
|  1 | programmi-2.txt    |          1 |
|  2 | programmi-re.txt   |          1 |
|  3 | readl-001.txt      |          2 |
|  4 | readl-002.txt      |          2 |
|  5 | readl-003.txt      |          2 |
|  6 | dict_class124.txt  |          3 |
|  7 | dict_class125.txt  |          3 |
|  8 | dict_class1264.txt |          3 |
|  9 | hello world        |          4 |
```

**Warning:**

Please note that this approach has an order-dependency: In the example below, comparing `dict_cl.txt` to the other names only leads to one match, while comparing `dict_class12.txt` to all other names leads to 3 matches. For your use case, where we assume that each group is very distinct from each other, this should not be a problem. However, this example shows that pairwise comparisons are a bit tricky in more sophisticated situations.

```
print(fuzz.ratio('dict_cl.txt', 'dict_class125.txt'))  # 79 -> not same category
print(fuzz.ratio('dict_cl.txt', 'dict_class1264.txt'))  # 76 -> not same category
print(fuzz.ratio('dict_cl.txt', 'dict_class12.txt'))  # 81 -> same category
print("###")
print(fuzz.ratio('dict_class12.txt', 'dict_cl.txt'))  # 81 -> same category
print(fuzz.ratio('dict_class12.txt', 'dict_class125.txt'))  # 97 -> same category
print(fuzz.ratio('dict_class12.txt', 'dict_class1264.txt'))  # 94 -> same category
```